# node.js, async, restify: cannot make restify call synchronous inside async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, restify

I am trying to enforce a few asynchronous functions in node.js, to execute synchronously. I am using async.series for that. Here's my code:

```
 async.series([
        function(callback){
            fs.truncateSync('rooms.txt', 0);
            console.log("function1 done");
            callback(null, 'one');
        },  
        function(callback){
            fs.truncateSync('sids.txt', 0);
            console.log("start loop");
            var count = 0;
            async.whilst(
                function () { return count <5 },
                function (callback) {
                    count++;
                    sid.generateSIDs; //---> PROBLEM!!
                    callback();
                },
                function (err) {
                }
            );
            var sids = fs.readFileSync('sids.txt').toString().split('\r\n');
            console.log("function2 done");
            callback(null, 'two');
        },
        function(callback){
            //lots of asynchronous callbacks
            callback(null, 'three');
        }
    ],
    function(err, results){
        // results is now equal to ['one', 'two', 'three'] 
    });
```

Everything is working as expected (sequentially) in the above code. But when I am adding the line, `sid.generateSIDs;`, marked as 'PROBLEM', everything is going for a toss! `generateSIDs` is a function inside an external node.js file called `sid.js`. It uses restify to post a couple of HTTP GETs asynchronously. Here is the code inside `sid.js`:

```
'use strict';

var requestify = require('requestify'); 
var fs = require('fs'); 
var response = "";
var sessionId="";   

function generateSIDs() {   
    //Request 1: Send Protocol Upgrade Request
    response = "";
    sessionId="";
            requestify.request('http://url.com', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Host': 'given',
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    'Origin': 'given',
                    'Referer': 'given'
                },
                cookies: {
                    'Cookie': 'given'
                },
                dataType: 'json'        
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                // get the response body
                response = response.getBody();
                sessionId = "extracted from response";

                //Request 2: Set up the session
                requestify.request('url.com'+sessionId, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Host': 'given',
                        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                        'Origin': 'given',
                        'Referer': 'given'
                    },
                    cookies: {
                        'Cookie': 'given'
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'        
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    fs.appendFile('sids.txt', sessionId+'\r\n', function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.tag("SERVER").log("file not opening: "+err);
                    });
                    console.log("file write done");
                });             
            }); 
};
exports.generateSIDs = generateSIDs();
```

From inside the `async.series()`, `generateSIDs()` is getting called once, generating a new sid, and then it is not iterating further. From the `console.log()` I could see that because of the asynchronous nature of the `restify` call, as soon as `sid.generateSIDs()` is called, before even one iteration of this function is finished, the third `function(callback)` in `async.series()` is getting triggered.

But, I want `sid.generateSIDs()` to run multiple times sequentially as per the while loop count. After these runs are done, then only I want third function(callback) to get executed. As you can understand from `generateSIDs()` code, I want multiple unique sid's to be created before the third function is called.

When I am running sid.js separately from command line (not in a loop)using `node sid.js`, each time it is running fine and creating a new sid for me.

I am new to node.js, and handling synchronous and asynchronous functions together in the same code, messes up my logic!! Can you please help me here?

Comment: `exports.generateSIDs = generateSIDs()` means it's only called once and only during `require`. Never anywhere else. What exactly did you intend with that?

Comment: Oh! Is it? So, in the line marked as PROBLEM, it is not getting called again and again? Each run of generateSIDs() created a new sid for me. Inside the async.whilst() loop, I want to call this function multiple times, say 5 times, so that the 5 sequential call to generateSIDs(), will create 5 new unique sids for me.

Comment: Correct. Each time you call `generateSID` creates new sid. However, you only call it once. In javascript, adding `()` to a function calls it. And you only do that once in your code.

Comment: Okay! How can i execute it multiple times?

Comment: Should I execute "node sid.js" using some system command inside the while? Is this doable? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution! I removed the execution of `sid.generateSIDs()` from inside `async.whilst()` loop in `async.series([])`. Instead I added the `async.whilst()` inside `sid.js` itself,lobal variables local. and made a couple of g Now, this is working as expected! Here is my updated code:

Updated code inside `async.series`:

```
   },  
        function(callback){
            fs.truncateSync('sids.txt', 0);
            console.log("start loop");
            var count = 0;
            async.whilst(
                function () { return count <5 },
                function (callback) {
                    count++;
                    sid.generateSIDs(num); //---> FIXED!
                    callback();
                },
                function (err) {
                }
            );
            console.log("function2 done");
            callback(null, 'two');
        },
```

Updated sid.js:

```
'use strict';

var requestify = require('requestify'); 
var fs = require('fs');  

function genEachSIDs() {   
    //Request 1: Send Protocol Upgrade Request
    var response = ""; //NOTE! I made this var local from global
    var sessionId=""; //NOTE! I made this var local from global to avoid override of values from one instance by another

    //code inside requestify.request( below is exactly same as given in the question above.
    requestify.request(
        //same code as above 
    );
}
// adding the while loop here!
module.exports generateSIDs = function generateSIDs(num){
        var count=0;
        async.whilst(
            function () { return count <num; },
            function (callback) {
                count++;
                genEachSIDs();
                callback();
            },
            function (err) {
            }
        );
    }
```

I removed the line: `var sids = fs.readFileSync('sids.txt').toString().split('\r\n');` from the 2nd function, because this again needs to wait till all sid creation are done.